# Half right reversed pyramid

Tags: c

I have a homework to make pyramid code, and then i have try and the code is something like this :

```
int main()
{
    int n,i,j,k;
    printf("How many lines long ?\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
for(i = 0; i<=n; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j<n-i; j++)
    {
        printf(" ");
    }
    for(k = 0; k<i; k++)
    {
        printf("#");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
return 0;
}
```

And after many try the result like this :

```
    #
   ##
  ###
 ####
#####
```

But, I want to make result like this :

```
#####
 ####
  ###
   ##
    #
```

Can anyone help me??? Thankyou...

Comment: Run the outer loop backwards?

Comment: Use your debugger? And fix your indenting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get this by just reversing the outer for loop. Make the outer for-loop `for(i = n; i>0; i--) {}`.

Modified code :-

```
int main()
{
    int n, i, j, k;
    printf("How many lines long ?\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (i = n; i > 0; i--)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n - i; j++)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
        for (k = 0; k < i; k++)
        {
            printf("#");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Output :-**

```
How many lines long ?
5
#####
 ####
  ###
   ##
    #
```

You can solve these simple problems by using a **debugger** .So learn using it. Or just by pen-paper writing. Also make sure that your code is properly indented.